# Mock response in API test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm attempting to test some API routes and my code coverage is good, but I'm consistently missing the `err` branch. Below is an example of one of my API route controllers.

```
var index = function(req, res) {
  request({url: privateUrl + '/players/' + req.params.playerId + '/games',
    headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    method: 'GET'}, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) {
        logger.warn('Error while retrieving games for player %d.', req.params.playerId, err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: err.message ? err.message : 'Error while retrieving player games.'
        });
      } else {
        res.json(helpers.JSONparse(body).response);
      }
    });
};
```

How would I test the `err` case? What I'd ideally like to do is `.set('err', true)` and then test that the `res.status` and `err.message` are what I'd expect. Here's the spec where I test a successful response:

```
it('should return an object with player games', function(done) {
  request
    .get('/api/players/' + playerId + '/games')
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('cookie', cookie)
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .end(function(err, res) {
      expect(err).toBeNull(err ? err.message : null);
      expect(res.body.games).toBeDefined();
      done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Postman for chrome is a great tool to test your API.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to throw an error in your REST call, just put "/player1/" instead of player, or intentionally bad data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a free HTTP mock service such as mockable.io. It's a great way of testing that an application can handle different types of responses, including errors. All that you change in your application code is the URL: you point the Ajax request, temporarily, to the URL of your mock API.